# c# reading a tab delimitted file into datatable

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetDataTable(@"C:\Documents and Settings\agordon\Desktop\ACTIVITYEX.csv");
    }
    public System.Data.DataTable GetDataTable(string strFileName)
    {
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = 
            new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
                ("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source = " 
                + System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(strFileName) 
                + ";Extended Properties = \"Text;HDR=YES;FMT=TabDelimited\"");
        conn.Open();
        string strQuery = "SELECT * FROM [" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(strFileName) + "]";
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strQuery, conn);
        System.Data.DataTable ds = new System.Data.DataTable("CSV File");
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        return ds;
    }
```

even though the data is tab delimitted it is writing an enter row into one datapoint. it is not recognizing the tabbing. here is an example of one of the tabs: `"  "`

here is an example of one row that it imported into one single data point:

> V2.00 Administrator       TX  0002    08:50
>   04/14/11  0   F   004 H   14400   0000    0000
>   ok    02  1   biscom-server   4321
>     Administrator           08:50:31
>   04/14/2011    08:50:33
>   04/14/2011    08:50:00
>   04/14/2011        12ffefe9-fa4f-4b45-8dcb-8ed2a2e28de3    419571  004 YES                 C:\MerthTesting\XIFINFax\Receive\20110414085022\FAX_8582170332_101169_20110413_13_36.pdf                                                                                normal  BISCOM-SERVER_Dev_1104141550330002

what am i doing wrong? what is the data being scrunched into one data point ?

Comment: I wonder if it is confused by the .csv extension and trying to parse it as that. Shouldn't be...

Comment: @tofu when i renamed it to .log, it said Cannot update.  Database or object is read-only.

Comment: Have you examined the file in a viewer that can display whitespace characters? I.e., are you sure you truly have tabs and not spaces?

Comment: @setho yessir, no problem at all with opening it with excel tab delimitted

Comment: That's really wierd.  Try .txt.

Comment: @tofu works but does not recognize the delimitted, just scrunches it into one column (the entire row)

Comment: Well, there's a line of text in the file that's not properly delimited.  We can't help you find it, you already know what it looks like.  Use a hex editor to look at the file so you can see 09 vs 20 (tab vs space).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone else had the exact same problem:

http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Offtopic/thread/9f7d2b67-cea5-4840-96ef-2e12011752d7